# ^^ binary operator in basic stamp

Tags: basic, binary-operators, stamp

We need to mantain a *.bas file (basic STAMP).
it contains the following line:

```
if (x^^y) then
```

We don't know what is the meaning of "^^" binary operator. (a single "^" is XOR and "^/" is XNOR). It's quite complicated to try to test it on the board.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is the meaning of the ^^ operator

Comment: Which BASIC interpreter/compiler are you using? I'm not immediately aware of any that uses `^/` as XNOR, but if you can identify it, it might be possible to find documentation for it somewhere...

Comment: Just guessing here, but if a single caret is XOR then a double caret might be a regular OR.  Is there a simple way to test it interpretively?

Comment: it's basic stamp. here is a guide http://peabody.sapp.org/class/dmp2/read/BASIC_Stamp_Manual_v2-0.pdf
Bill - i will check with the relevant person.

Comment: My guess is that the line is in error, since there appears to be no mention of a double-caret operator in the provided manual.  Does the code run or are you debugging it?

Comment: The code is already burned on the component and works in production for years. The requirement is to make some change in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"^^" is a logical XOR operation, just like "||" and "&&" are OR and AND logical operations.

"^" operator represents a XOR operation as i said, but it is a bitwise XOR operation, not logical, just like "|" is bitwise OR and "&" is bitwise AND.

(We burned it on the component.)

Comment: It is most likely that ^^ is a bitwise xor.